# selenium upload file java ChromeDriver/FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to automate a test that uploads a picture.  I can add text to the 'Title' box, but when I enter the location of the file, I can successfully enter the text, but the website tells me that I have not uploaded a valid .jpg file.  When I do the test manually, I can't enter the text, but I can browse for the file and it uploads successfully. Here is my code:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='FakeInputName2']")).sendKeys("C:\\Users\\MyUsername\\Pictures\\Lighthouse.jpg");
```

Here is what the HTML code looks like:

```
<tr>
<td align="right"> Image: </td>
<td>
    <div id="RenamedUpload1" class="RenameUpload RenameUpload RenameUpload_Office2007">
        <ul id="RenameUpload1ListContainer" class="renamedInputs">
            <li id="RenameUpload1row0">
                <span class="blerghFileWrap blerghStyled">
                    <input id="FakeInputName" class="renamedThisFakeInput somethingNoDecorate" type="text" tabindex="-1" size="67">
                    <label for="FakeInputName" style="display:none">label</label>
                    <input class="notButton notBrowse" type="button" tabindex="-1" value="Select" style="border: 0px dotted;">
                    <input id="FakeInputName2" class="notFileInput" type="file" tabindex="0" name="FakeInputName2" size="68">
                    <label for="FakeInputName2" style="display:none">label</label>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</td>
```

I also tried the Runtime.getRuntime() thing that other answers to similar questions suggested.  That didn't work at all.  Can anyone help?

Here is the console output and stack trace (To clarify (MyClass line 114 is where the line `String filePath = url.getFile();` goes):

```
Creating Chrome webdriver... Starting ChromeDriver (v2.8.241075) on port 14489
Process took 2 seconds.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at builderselenium.MyClass.runUseCase(MyClass.java:114)
at builderselenium.UseCase.run(UseCase.java:104)
at builderselenium.TestDriver.runUseCase(TestDriver.java:165)
at builderselenium.MyGUI.runUseCase(MyGUI.java:410)
at builderselenium.MyGUI.actionPerformed(MyGUI.java:299)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "*.jpeg"-File isn't a valid .jpg file.

Can you show at least the html-Code of the fileUpload?

Are you sure your JVM has access to the file? Maybe you should add the file to your resources-folder. If your file is stored in "[...]\workspace\projcetname\src\test\resources" this should work:

```
String pathToUpload = "/Lighthouse.jpg";
URL url = MYCLASSNAME.class.getResource(pathToUpload);
String filePath = url.getFile();
System.out.print(filePath);
File imgToUpload = new File(filePath);
String absolutePath = imgToUpload.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.print(absolutePath);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='FakeInputName2']")).sendKeys(absolutePath);
System.out.print(driver.getPageSource());
```

Be careful: 'Myclass' has to be replaced with your current classname.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work, it didn't even enter the path into the text box. And I was trying it with jpeg and jpg, but I have it as jpg now.

Comment: This shouldn't enter the path into "//input[@id='FakeInputName']", it should just add the filepath to the file-Upload-Input. I added some output in the code above. I should help finding the problem. Are you sure your ID is unique? 'findElement' takes the first element fitting the by-description.

Comment: Is there a piece of your code I'm missing? It's not even getting to the xpath.  It throws a NullPointerException at the File imgToUpload = new File... line.  Yes, I changed MyClass to reflect my class name.  Will it be mad because my class extends an abstract class?

Comment: I don't think the abstract class could be a problem. I guess the path is the problem. What is the absolute path to your img?

Comment: C:\Users\MyUser\Pictures\Lighthouse.jpg works, and so does C:\Users\MyUser\stuff\projName\projectName\projectName\src\test\resources\Lighthouse.jpg.  At this point I have the file stored in multiple locations.  My code uses double slashes, of course.

Comment: Uh no, sorry.  That means those path names are correct because they work for other applications.

Comment: I've changed the code above to find the nullpointer. Please try it and post the stacktrace and the consoleoutput.

Comment: I've added the stacktrace and output

Comment: Sorry, i've made a terrible copy and paste mistake with the last edit on the code. You used `FileDownloader.class.getResource`...but "FileDownloader" is the Name of my Helperclass where i copied the code from. So your stacktrace talks about a ClassNotFoundException. that"s not surprising. Please replace MYCLASSNAME with z your classname.

Comment: This time it threw a NullPointerException at the url.getFile() line.

Comment: That means your URL-Object is null. The 'getResource()'-Methode Returns a URL object for reading the resource, or null if the resource could not be found or the invoker doesn't have adequate privileges to get the resource. In other words: either your pathToUpload isn't correct or there is no access to this file. Maybe there is another Programm accessing this file? Im a bit concerned about your stacktrace, there are some mouseevents, which I did not expected at this point.

Comment: If instead of "/Lighthouse.jpg", I use "\\Lighthouse.jpg" for the String pathToUpload and put the picture in the src file directly, it does not produce a NullPointerException.  In fact it runs all the way through and, on the webpage, I get the same message I've been getting: "Valid file(*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png*;*.zip;.doc;*.pdf) not selected".  I tried it with .png files and .doc files and got the same error.  It is seeming more and more that this is a bug on the webpage itself, and not a problem with my code.